# Can't upload video files

Tags: php, video, file-upload

That's my code

```
<?php 
    mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','vuap');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $temp = $_FILES['file']['temp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
        mysqli_query("INSERT INTO video ('movie') VALUE (''$name')" );

    }


    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" >
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="gonder">
    </form>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "<br>".$name."has been uploaded";
    };
    ?>
```

I can upload images but not videos, for some reason.

Comment: Whats the error? Check max upload limit, and max post size in php.ini. VALUE (''$name') , remove one quote there, '$name', dont forget to escape

Comment: first of all upper code must be down inside `<?php` and also two times `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` is not correct too.

Comment: This `mysqli_query("INSERT INTO video ('movie') VALUE (''$name')" );` is breaking your query for three reasons. IF... that's your real code. And no, it's not `VALUE`. It's to the left and right of it and what you didn't do, *execute the query*. Using http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have told you about the syntax errors.

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using?

Comment: Using http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would tell you if that video file's too large also. Too many possible reasons for your code to fail and as I already outlined. Basic rule of thumb: check for errors.

Comment: I write sql BLOB and working. my php.ini max upload limit 300MB it no error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few things wrong in your code.

This `mysqli_query("INSERT INTO video ('movie') VALUE (''$name')" );` is breaking your query for three reasons.

- Wrong identifier qualifiers
- Extra quote for the VALUE
- Not executing the query

**IF**... that's your real code.

And no, it's not `VALUE`,  it's what's to the left and right of it and what you didn't do, *execute the query*.

- Consult: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Using error checking http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php on your query, would have told you about the syntax errors you made being using the identifier qualifiers for your table being regular quotes, rather than ticks or no quotes at all, and the additional quote in `''$name'`.

Consult the following on identifier qualifiers in MySQL:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

You also need to assign a variable to your connection and check for errors.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','vuap') 
            or die (mysqli_error($connect));
```

Then add that to your query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO video (`movie`) VALUE ('$name')" );
```

then

```
if(!$result){

   echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($connect);

}

else {
   echo "Success!";
}
```

You also don't need this, just remove it:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "<br>".$name."has been uploaded";
};
```

and make sure that the folder you're wanting to upload to, has the proper permissions to write to it and that the video you're wanting to upload is within the maximum allowed size.

Consult: [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

**Sidenote:** For those who think that `VALUE` isn't valid, it is in MySQL.

Consult: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Example:

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)] 
    [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

---

**Footnotes:**

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

**Additional notes:**

If you're wanting to upload the data as binary rather than a string, then you will need to use either BLOB or LONGBLOB and escape the data.

Otherwise, it will throw you an error.

I.e.:

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $name);
```

Consult the manual on BLOB:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/blob.html

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: @Anant Thanks. Let's only hope now, that I haven't given them *too much information* or *not enough*. Or, that they come back and say: *"It doesn't work"*. Lordie.

Comment: ha ha ha. sometimes its undigested to new coders. I agreed with that